# StripeCheckout - How to pass Additional data to handleToken function?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

How would I be able to pass a parameter to the handleToken function from the StripeCheckout Button?

As it seems that the only parameters that It will take is token

```
const handleToken = (token) => {

    axios.post("/checkout", { token }).then((res) => {
      let status = res.data.status;

      if (status === "success") {
        sweetalert2.fire("Successfully Paid Invoice", "", "success");
      } else {
        sweetalert2.fire({
          icon: "error",
          title: "Something Went Wrong",
        });
      }

    });

  };
```

```
<StripeCheckout
   stripeKey="#"
   image={logo}
   token={handleToken}
   amount={100}
   currency="AUD"
   email={c.email}
>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use Stripe's legacy Checkout here, which has been deprecated and is not recommended.

Instead you should look into either using the [new Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) or using Stripe's [official React library](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js)

To answer your question, you can pass in an anonymous function in your props:

```
<StripeCheckout
   stripeKey="#"
   image={logo}
   token={(token) => {     
     handleToken(token, 'foo');
   }}
   amount={100}
   currency="AUD"
   email={c.email}
>
```

Just make sure that `handleToken` can be accessed from within that scope.